# El SDK de MercadoPago para Swift está devolviendo "invalid device_name" al terminar el pago

Tags: ios, swift, mercadopago

El SDK me da la opción de Reintentar al terminar el pago. Al revisar los logs de la consola, veo lo siguiente (evitando colocar aquí mis credenciales de MercadoPago y uuid de mi device):

```
--REQUEST_URL: https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/card_tokens?access_token={access_token}&public_key={public_key}
--REQUEST_BODY: {"cardholder":{"name":"APRO","identification":{"number":"35265325","type":"DNI"}},"card_number":"4509953566233704","device":{"fingerprint":{"vendor_specific_attributes":{"simulator":0,"device_name":"Fernando Martín’s iPhone","can_send_sms":1,"can_make_phone_calls":1,"device_idiom":"Phone","device_model":"iPhone","device_languaje":"es-AR"},"model":"iPhone","os":"iOS","system_version":"11.0","vendor_ids":[{"name":"vendor_id","value":{mi_vendor_id}},{"name":"uuid","value":{mi_uuid}}],"resolution":"375x667"}},"expiration_year":2019,"security_code":"222","expiration_month":11}
--REQUEST_RESPONSE: {"message":"invalid device_name","status":400,"error":"bad_request","cause":[{"description":"invalid device_name","code":"G001"}]}
```

La descripción del error sugiere que se trata de un nombre de dispositivo inválido. Al intentar realizar la misma request por Postman, me sigue devolviendo el mismo error.

Pero si cambio:

```
"device_name": "Fernando Martín’s iPhone"
```

por:

```
"device_name": "iPhone 6"
```

Entonces no recibo ningún tipo de error y la transacción se ejecuta correctamente.
Ahora, no veo la manera de manipular este dato por medio del SDK ¿Puede tratarse de un error del SDK? Mi implementación estaba funcionando hace algún tiempo.

Incluso intenté actualizando la versión del SDK a la última disponible, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desconozco el como funciona mercado pago, pero por lo que describes en tu problema, pareciera que el problema está en el tilde de "Martín".
Puedes probar a convertir con html entities para mandar el valor. Algo así como `&#237;` o `%C3%AD`.

Si eso no funciona, podrías a revisar que codificación de caracteres estás usando (y cual necesita mercadopago).

Comment: Era exactamente eso. Me rechazaba la request por la tilde. De todos modos, la request no la armaba yo, sino que el mismo SDK lo hace por detrás. Con cambiarle el nombre a mi device desde el Xcode empezó a funcionar.